# Kernel not upgraded during upgrade to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit to 15.10 64-bit. Afterwards the kernel shows an older version than that installed:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-57-generic
```

Even though 4.2 is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic       3.19.0-15.15                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic       3.19.0-22.22                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic       3.19.0-28.30                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic        4.2.0-16.19                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic 3.19.0-15.15                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-22-generic 3.19.0-22.22                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic 3.19.0-28.30                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic  4.2.0-16.19                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 4.2.0.16.18                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Tried re-installing linux-general as per some other threads but no luck:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
[sudo] password for chris: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,658 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 60056 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_4.2.0.16.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.2.0.16.18) over (4.2.0.16.18) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.2.0.16.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.2.0.16.18) over (4.2.0.16.18) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.2.0.16.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.2.0.16.18) over (4.2.0.16.18) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.2.0.16.18) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.2.0.16.18) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.2.0.16.18) ...
```

I've rebooted loads of times, still nothing.

What should I do to correctly install the kernel? It's preventing me from running iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:578 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-57-generic/modules.dep.bin'
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Any ideas appreciated. If relevant, this is on a DigitalOcean droplet.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your kernel 4.2 is correctly installed (as the `ii` left of the package's name indicates). Maybe you only need to update your grub configuration to take that new kernel into account ?

Did you try the `sudo update-grub` command, followed by a reboot ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is definitely a dupe of the other questions. I've been doing a command line reboot all this time and nothing. Actually power cycling fixed it fine.

Can't recall seeing that behaviour before, but maybe that's peculiar to DigitalOcean/VM or something.

thanks for the advice!